# Atler Table Alter Column Set Default FALSE: Why my alter table took 10 minutes to finish?

Tags: postgresql, alter-table

I have run the following command and it took about 10 minutes to finish:

```
ALTER TABLE "bookings" ALTER COLUMN "local_direct_booking" SET DEFAULT FALSE
```

for a table `bookings` which had 111.834 rows (about 111K rows).

I don't believe this is a big table.

This is the size of the table:

```
lvd-am::DATABASE=> SELECT pg_size_pretty( pg_total_relation_size('bookings') );
 pg_size_pretty 
----------------
 213 MB
(1 row)
```

Do you have any hint why this might have taken that long?

Comment: It probably had to wait for the lock.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There must have been a concurrent long running transaction that used (perhaps read from) the table. Check `pg_stat_activity` for sessions with a `state` other than `idle`.